# pandas data frame cannot get value

Tags: python, json, string, pandas, series

I have a pandas data frame that has the following structure:

```
id, @text, values
0, ....., "{'organizations':['sdfsf','sfdsf','sdfs'],'content':'some text'}"
```

I am trying to get the value "some text" in 'content'

```
Expected output is:

"some text"
```

I tried the following saving the "{'organizations':['sdfsf','sfdsf','sdfs'],'content':'some text'}" in a json doc but got a 'circular reference error'

```
import json
json_data = pandas_dataframe.get(["value"][0])
with open('/pddata.json', 'w') as fp:  
    json.dump(json_data, fp)
```

Comment: what is your expected output. Can you brief it with example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval()`

Example:

```
import ast
df = pd.DataFrame([123, 'abc', "{'organizations':['sdfsf','sfdsf','sdfs'],'content':'some text'}"]).T
df.columns = ['id', 'text', 'values']
df
#     id    text    values
# 0  123    abc {'organizations':['sdfsf','sfdsf','sdfs'],'con...

to_fetch = ast.literal_eval(df.iloc[0,2])
type(to_fetch)
# dict

to_fetch['content']
# 'some text'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) twice, first with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), then with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from ast import literal_eval
from operator import itemgetter

df['content'] = df['values'].map(literal_eval).map(itemgetter('content'))

print(df)

    id text                                             values    content
0  123  abc  {'organizations':['sdfsf','sfdsf','sdfs'],'con...  some text
```

`literal_eval` converts the string to a dictionary, `itemgetter` extracts a value given a key argument. `pd.Series.map` applies a function to every value in a series.

Or with `map` + `lambda`, an anonymous custom function:

```
df['content'] = df['values'].map(lambda x: literal_eval(x)['content'])
```

Comment: Looks very pythonic! :) 

Can you also add some explanation to the line of code to help us understand better.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it :) 

This should have been the accepted answer (in my opinion) since it applies to multiple rows in a larger dataframe.